# What AWS IAM policy can be used to to restrict a user to a limited number of instance types

Tags: amazon-web-services

Using an AWS Identity Access Management (IAM) policy, is it possible to restrict the following items for users launching EC2 instances:

1. Instance type EG t2.small, t2.medium, etc
2. Number of instances launched. Restrict to a fixed maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict a policy to allow only certain instance types:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:region::image/ami-*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:subnet/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:network-interface/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:volume/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:key-pair/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:region:account:security-group/sg-12345678"
      ],
      "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:InstanceType": "m1.small"
            }
        }
    }
   ]
}
```

This policy allows a user to launch an instance in a VPC, but only an m1.small instance type.

You can further restrict permissions to specific AMIs, Subnets etc.  For example, the security group here is restricted to one specific policy.

You cannot limit the number of instances launched via an IAM policy.

See [IAM user to limit number of ec2 instances and type](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=174503) and [Example Policies for Working in the Amazon EC2 Console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-ec2-console.html)

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know, the only way to do so is put a logical layer with code between the end users and AWS, e.g using some python boto script. You can also either deploy a web interface calling your scripts, or use a tool like rundeck, jenkins or whatever, and create jobs in those interfaces.